# Parse partial html string and isolate specific numbers

Tags: php, scanf, text-parsing

I need to grab the number of pages from the following text:

```
<font size="1" color="blue" face="Verdana, Arial">Page 1 of 5 / 22 Records
```

I have no experience with regex. Since I mostly program in C, I tried this:

```
sscanf($result, "Page 1 of %d", $Npages);
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: "But it doesn't work" is the most useless statement that you have made in your life, ever, guaranteed. What does "doesn't work" mean? What _precisely_ did you witness, and in what way did it differ from the behaviour you desire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php
$str = '<font size="1" color="blue" face="Verdana, Arial">Page 1 of 5 / 22 Records';

if (preg_match('!Page.*?(\d+)\s+/.+Records!', $str, $matches)) {
    $pages = $matches[1];
    echo $pages;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but that returns the number of records. Not the number of pages.

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there. PHP's [`sscanf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php) can either return the output, or take a [reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) to fill with the parsed value. In your code, it looks like you're trying to use a reference, but you're not specifying it as such. A reference in PHP is specified by a `&` before the variable name, so you could have used:

```
sscanf($result, "Page 1 of %d", &$npages);
```

Alternately, `sscanf` will return an array of all parsed values if you don't pass any variables by reference:

```
$result = "Page 1 of 5 / 22 Records";
var_dump(sscanf($result, "Page %d of %d / %d Records"));
/*
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(5)
  [2]=>
  int(22)
}
*/
```

You could then use [`list`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) to assign that array to variables:

```
list($page, $npages, $nrecords) = sscanf($result, "Page %d of %d / %d Records");
```

Comment: Thank you. That does work if I just use that string. Is there any limit for the amount of text sscanf supports? Because I'm retrieving the page through cURL, so my variable has a lot more text.

Comment: @Cornwell not as far as I'm aware of (or is mentioned in the manual page)

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
#<font[^>]*>(.*)\/(.*) Records<\/font>#is
```

Second array element will have the #.

Barry

Answer (score 0):

$str= YOUT STRING;

preg_match('/Page \d+ of \d+ / (\d+) Records/', $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);

Comment: the (\d+) token will group de number of pages and insert them into the $matches array.